# Problem with texture mapping in react-three-fiber (three.js)

Tags: reactjs, three.js, mesh, texture-mapping, react-three-fiber

I want to **apply** this texture to one part of my *yacht model*:

[image]

In **Blender** it looks quite normal:

[image]

But in **my browser** I am getting this ugly result:

[image]

[image]

My **code** looks like this:

```
import { TextureLoader, MeshBasicMaterial } from 'three'
import leatherImage from '../../../assets/fabric_leather_02_diff_1k.jpg'

const initialTexture = new TextureLoader().load(leatherImage)
export const initialMaterial5 = new MeshBasicMaterial({ map: initialTexture })

//...

;(model.children[5] as Mesh).material = initialMaterial5
```

I have no idea what am I doing wrong here. **UV vectors** seem to be normal and other textures are also work quite fine.

Will be grateful for any ideas on how to solve this!

Comment: Are you sure that UV is correct? Three.js supports multiple UVs only for ao and lightmap. Is it a gltf model? If you don't have to change texture in the runtime, you can export binary gltf with all textures. Would you mind verifying how is your model presented in that viewer: https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/

Comment: Thanks, I am using fbx model and changing textures in runtime is a key functionality there as it is a web-configurator. Problem actually was that I’ve incorrectly set texture.wrapS and wrapT properties. I’ve also specified repeat and now everything’s just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that the texture is not «big» enough to map correctly. I’ve explicitly specified this properties to make sure that texture **will be repeated** to fully map the model even if it is relatively small:

```
initialTexture.wrapS = initialTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping

initialTexture.repeat.set(3, 3)
```